# Log out user to change home dir and then re login - Linux

Tags: linux

I'm trying to change git user's home directory using:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/git git
```

However, the response I receive is: "user git is currently logged in".
How can I logout that user, change the home directory and then login it again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find processes/services started under user git:

```
ps axu | grep "^git"
```

And stop/kill them all.
Then you will be able to change home directory for this user.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the account database directly, using `vipw`. The file format is described in *[passwd(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/passwd.5.html)*.